# Shimano PF-M545 pedals Mavic Alpine All Mountain Shoes how to fit the cleats

Tags: pedals, clipless, shoes, spd

I just bought Shimano PD-M545 pedals and Mavic Alpine All Mountain Shoes (links below)

- [Shimano M545 Free Ride Pedals](http://www.wiggle.co.uk/shimano-m545-free-ride-pedals/)
- [Mavic Alpine All Mountain Shoes](http://www.wiggle.co.uk/mavic-alpine-all-mountain-shoes/?&source=MaxiFeed&id=5360056181)

I did do some research and "think" I got the best thing for me for the money I had, and that they work together, [Bike radar says they are SPD type shoes](http://www.bikeradar.com/commuting/gear/category/clothing/shoes/product/alpine-shoes-42675/).  They seemed to look right.

They arrived today and I sat down to try and fit the cleats to the shoe.  My problem is the 4 screws that came with the pedals are larger than the screw holes in the sole of the shoes.  It almost looks like there is an inner screw hole in the shoe, (but I could be wrong).  It doesn't seem like it should be a complicated process.. Have I bought the wrong shoes, being completely stupid or missing something?

Thanks for any and all help, (this is my first time with any clipless shoe).

Comment: http://techdocs.shimano.com/techdocs/blevel.jsp?ASSORTMENT%3C%3East_id=1408474395181679&FOLDER%3C%3Efolder_id=2534374302051175&bmUID=iWdu82r

Comment: http://www.mavic.com/en/product/footwear/mountain-bike/footwear/Alpine

Comment: thanks for links.  I had the same manuals as the shimano's and didn't find anything helpful (just sales stuff) for the Mavic

Comment: turns out that there was a male screw thread inside the female and I needed an alan key to get it out, (had to go to bike shop to learn that though).

Comment: Can you please answer this or close it? It shows as unanswered because you discovered the solution yourself and announced it in a comment. Even pasting that comment into an answer would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that there was a male screw thread inside the female and I needed an allen key to get it out. (I had to go to bike shop to learn that, though.)

After that point the rest was clear sailing, following the instructions closely, and watching some online video tutorials about it.

Comment: I did it all with my ToPeak Hexus II.